# Jquery - using "this" to dynamically show and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, show-hide

```
<div class="show_hide panel-header" rel="#panel">
    <h4>Disclaimer</h4>
</div>
<div id="panel" class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Above is my **HTML** ... a simple `div` for the *header* (event handler) and the *hidden* `div` to show/hide. Works perfectly for a simple show/hide, but I may have several panels on screen at once and I don't want to explicitly ID each one and give it it's own function. How can I use the `this` selector to achieve dynamic interactions?

My **JQuery** currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".panel").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show(); //Probably don't need this line...
        $('.show_hide').click(function(){
            $(this).children("div").slideToggle();
        });           
    });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm new to JS/JQuery and having some trouble understanding the different selectors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `div` isn't a child, it's the `next` div in line:

```
$(this).next("div.panel").slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".panel").hide();
        $('.show_hide').click(function(){
            $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
        });           
    });
</script>
```